# 'sstableloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I have bunch of `SSTables` with me that I got from somebody within my team. Now I was trying to push those `SSTABLES` into `Cassandra database`.

I created corresponding keyspace and column family successfully.

Now as soon as I execute `SSTableLoader` command, I always get below exception?

```
S:\Apache Cassandra\apache-cassandra-1.2.3\bin>sstableloader
C:\CassandraClient-LnP\201304050000\profileks\PROFILECF 'sstableloader' is
not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
batch file.
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here? I am running Cassandra 1.2.3. And this is my first time working with `SSTableLoader`. I am working in windows environment.

Comment: Is sstableloader supported in windows, looking at the source it seems to be unix shell file.

Comment: I am also not sure about that. And I don't think so that will be the case. Meaning in windows, we cannot use `SSTableLoader`?

Comment: Most of the work is probably done in java code, the shell script just sets up the arguments for java.  It shouldn't be hard to port the shell script to a .bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSTableLoader` is a Unix executable and cant be run under windows (as far as I know).

You could try exporting your tables as `json` and re-import them (using [**json2sstable**](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/sstable2json)) but to use the sstableloader you need linux/mac/solaris etc.