# Cassandra loads data incorrect

Tags: database, cassandra

Problem:
I copied some data from a cassandra cluster and want to add this to an other one noded cluster. But when I load the data all the column data is written as row key in my database.

Cassandra version: 1.1.6

I have no clue what I have done wrong.

Edit:

I copied the stored sstables from one cluster(out of the data file directory of cassandra) into my new cluster.
With copying I mean CTRL-C and CTR-V on Windows.

When I restart the cluster after that the data in the columnfamilies looks like this:

```
Row Key                                                                  Columns
Movelet_{[1014][C2AED5777E365035DA700000]:[INVOICE]:[null]} 
Movelet_{[1014][C2AED57754835035DA6D0000]:[INVOICE]:[100]}  
Movelet_{[1011][0AFE012A175E5051B73C2929]:[INVOICE]:[100]}  
Movelet_{[1011][0AFE012A2873505C37B31058]:[INVOICE]:[null]} 
Movelet_{[1011][0AFE012A17645051B7091825]:[INVOICE]:[null]} 
Movelet_{[1009][C11132380A70501A3E88177B]:[INVOICE]:[100]}  
Movelet_{[1014][C2AED57754835035E1060305]:[INVOICE]:[null]}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, like how you specifically copied the data?

Comment: I edited my start post. But for the record: I copied the stored sstables from one cluster(out of the data file directory of cassandra) into my new cluster. With copying I mean CTRL-C and CTR-V on Windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a snapshot,
2. load using `sstableloader`

read more here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/backup_restore

Comment: This means that I have to use linux when I want to migrate data?

Comment: When I want to use the sstableloader script, or is it also available for windows?

Comment: ah, you are right. Sorry, do not use Windows anywhere. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164707/298455

Comment: My problem is still not solved, I followed the instructions for bulkloading etc. but the data in my db still looks like I showed in my question. But thanks for your help, at least I took the opportunity to install an ubuntu and tested the sstableloader :)

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu. I left Windows 2 years ago, no regrets. Except for may be Photoshop. I have migrated data using sstableloader earlier. It worked pretty flawlessly.